# Using Beautiful Soup Twice

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to call another instance of BS4 but it always give me the error:

```
'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'.
```

Anyone have any ideas?

```
import lxml, bs4, requests, re

url = 'https://www.sample_url.html'
r = requests.get(url)
type(r)

bs4 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
type(bs4)

article = bs4.findAll('article') 
url_key = article[0]['data-offer-id']

print(url_key)

url_new = url + '?rc=' + url_key

print(url_new)

r1 = requests.get(url_new)
type(r1)

bs41 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r1.content, 'html.parser')

type(bs41)

code = bs4.select('title')

print(code)
```

Comment: Can you works your code to remove all lines that are not mandatory to produce your error ? I suppose that IF you remove all print() lines, the error occurs again ! If yes, remove all these lines from your code; so that at end, your code contains only interesting lines :-)

Comment: First question I've ever posted so cut some slack eh. But thanks for the help :)

Comment: I see that it is your first post, because it is the role of members that has a little reputation to check FIRST input of user and to give some advice before accepting a first question. In the following context, I can change your question myself but I prefer that you do that yourself because I think you know Python.

Comment: I vote down because this question is not enough documented and user doesn't take any effort to enhance this question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning `bs4` on the

```
bs4 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

line, so at

```
bs41 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r1.content, 'html.parser')
```

`bs4` won't be the module.

I suggest renaming that first `bs4 = ...` to `soup = ...`, maybe.

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a simple solution, don't know why I didn't do this sooner!